# Magento2 Db schema

Tags: magento2

can any one explain this code line

```
<constraint xsi:type="foreign" referenceId="SALES_ORDER_CUSTOMER_ID_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID" table="sales_order" column="customer_id" referenceTable="customer_entity" referenceColumn="entity_id" onDelete="SET NULL"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The line of code:

```
<constraint xsi:type="foreign" referenceId="SALES_ORDER_CUSTOMER_ID_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID" table="sales_order" column="customer_id" referenceTable="customer_entity" referenceColumn="entity_id" onDelete="SET NULL"/>
```

is being used to define the foreign key constraint for a table.

**xsi:type="foreign":** to define foreign key

**referenceId="SALES_ORDER_CUSTOMER_ID_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID":** Reference ID for the foreign key

**table="sales_order":** table which has the foreign key column

**column="customer_id":** foreign key column

**referenceTable="customer_entity":** reference table

**referenceColumn="entity_id":** reference column in the reference table

**onDelete="SET NULL":** beviour on delete value in parent table

You can compare it with the InstallSchema.php or UpgradeSchema.php with foreign key constraint in Magento 2.2.x version for better understanding.

Comment: this error Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (au.#sql-40d4_c, CONSTRAINT SALES_ORDER_CUSTOMER_ID_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_  when i run upgrade command

Comment: Please match the constraint name with the previous version.

Comment: you mean foregin i just upgrade from 2.2.8 to 2.3.3

Comment: I think you need to ask another question because my answer satisfies what you have asked in the current question. You can post your query in detail in a new question. In comments, you can only post your doubts regarding current question.